Identifying a Japanese movie about swordswomen
I am looking for a Japanese movie that I watched a long time ago. It looks like it was made during the 70's, or the 80's at most. In the movie, there was a woman who seems to be a brothel mistress (who has underlings, so she might also be a yakuza mistress), who when she fights (with a short sword) reveals her barred right hands with tattoos on shoulder. She raised a girl who grows up to be a geisha or a prostitute, who fights with two weapons at the same time: a sword and a rhythmic gymnastic-styled ribbon. 
My English wasn't very good to understand what happens in the movie, except at the end the women seem to fight some kind of crooked police who has colluded with the older one earlier in something involving the younger girl (might be the murder of her parents), which leads to him being slain. The cover of the video tape has the closeup photo of the two female characters, the older woman's arm barred like I described above. I think this is the only movie in which the ribbon is used as weapon.
The movie seems to belong to the jidaigeki genre, not an attempt to be artistic. And it is not Lady Snowblood. Sorry for the little amount of information; like I said, I was very clueless back then. Thanks so much.

I got the answer from another website. The movie is called "Death Shadow", directed by Hideo Gosha.

Three men sentenced to death for sundry crimes discover that other men have been beheaded in their place. They now no longer exist, & will be killed if they do not serve well as shogunate "shadow police."
To insure they never speak of their secret triad of "dead" shadow-police, each man has his voicebox punctured. They are then armed with a sword-truncheon, a weapon that combines the shortsword with the jitte badge of a police officer.
Thus with cruelty & gloom begins Death Shadows (Jittemei, 1986), with the forceful induction & eternal silencing of the criminals Otomatsu, Yasuke, & Kapachi.
They spent their next twenty years under deep cover & servitude as extra-legal government assassins targetting criminal elements, permitted no lives of their own.
One of the three, Yasuke the Viper (Takuzo Kawatani), has a daughter in the yakuza underground, Ocho. She trained to be a killer with the unfilial plan to kill her father who abandoned her & her mom.
Her weapon of choice, a long pretty ribbon, is just about the most assinine thing any film ever pretended could cut & kill people.

